# Grabbing DHCP from DMZ?

Tags: networking, router, nat, dmz

Is it possible to grab DHCP from the DMZ of a router above?

Essentially i want to have a setup like this.

```
DMZ DHCP ------> Router (master router)
                   |
                   |
                   |
                   |
              -----|-----
             |           |
             |           |
             |           |
           Router      Router
           |    |      |    |
           PC   PC     PC   PC
```

The Routers below the master router will get their IP from the master router. But i want the PC clients to get their IP's from the DMZ using dhcp.

Is something like this possible? Assuming i create the firewall rules to do so?

Comment: You're going to want to look into DHCP forwarding. But your router has to be able to handle multiple IP ranges. And your secondary routers should probably have their addresses assigned based on their MAC address. Why not just set up DHCP on the secondary routers though?

Comment: They want to use a system to deliver timed internet services for money @OliverSalzburg

Comment: Can you disable DHCP on the three routers?

Answer (score 2):

Short version: not easily, or without higher end routers.

As mentioned in the comments, a router capable of doing DHCP forwarding (sometimes referred to with a DHCP helper-address) could do that, and probably also handle routing the additional subnets needed to do such a thing... You may then also have NAT concerns to deal with. This gets very complex very quickly and is certainly beyond the ability of stock firmware on "consumer grade" routers.

If I understand/assume correctly, the root of the DMZ is some device that hands out multiple IPs on a metered basis. What purpose do the other routers serve? If they're just there to do something like add additional ports or extend WiFi range you can use a simple network switch or wireless AP to transparently pass the traffic instead of the routers.